# Probability mass function of time of first head

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, geometric-distribution

This is an exercise from the probability book by Ross. This is not homework.

[image]

Using conditional probability and the distribution of sum of two geometric random variables, the probability comes out to be $\frac{1}{(n-1)}$.

But I am not able to understand how can the same probability be deduced from just the hint without all the computations.

I am not sure but it seems to have to do with each of the previous $(n-1)$ tosses being equally probable of being the time of the first head. Is that correct?

Comment: One head occurs among the first $n-1$ flips.  On which flip did it occur?  Does the coin favor showing heads at any particular time compared to any other time?

Comment: @whuber As the coin is unbiased, all flips have the same probability of landing in heads. So no, the coin doesn't favor showing heads at any particular flip.

Comment: @whuber I am confused regarding the distinction between the event of getting a head in the i-th flip and the i-th flip being the time of first head.

Comment: Suppose the coin flips go T, H, T, H, ....  You obtain a head on the i = 4th flip, but the *first* head was obtained on the i = 2nd flip.